# Can we find the iDevice model?

Tags: ios

Can we retrieve the iDevice Model like it is shown in

**Settings->General->About->Model = MD662F** ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. [`UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW1) has a "model" property, but will only return  @”iPhone” and @”iPod touch”, etc.

```
UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *model = [currentDevice model];
NSLog(@"Device Model: %@", model);
```